# Does the writeback dataset automatically update when I make edits?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph, foundry-object-views

I want to use the Phonograph writeback dataset for downstream analysis in Foundry. When I make an edit to Phonograph, will the writeback dataset be automatically updated too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the writeback dataset only gets built automatically when registration with Phonograph is updated. Typically, users:

1. Build the writeback dataset on a recurring schedule appropriate for the use-case (e.g. every day), or
2. Build on-demand when analysis is needed.