# How can I keep my writeback dataset up to date without wasting resources?

Tags: palantir-foundry

As clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556940/does-the-writeback-dataset-automatically-update-when-i-make-edits), object type writeback datasets do not automatically update when object edits are made. I need to build the writeback dataset for it to reflect the latest object edits.

How can I then minimise the latency of my writeback dataset without wasting build resources when there have not actually been any edits since the last build?

Answer (score 3):

I can put a time-based schedule on the writeback dataset (and include any downstream datasets) at my desired frequently as necessary.

By leaving the 'Force build' option in the Scheduler unticked, this schedule will then only actually trigger a build when the writeback dataset has become stale (due to recent object edits). This prevents wasting build resources.

[image: Leave the first option unticked]